# Extjs 5.1.3 in tbar add button who mask/unmask grid

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, grid

In Extjs, i want to add button in tbar chart, which hide/unhide my grid, i have some difficult with layout, so in certains case, my button take 100% place, also my grid disapear, my code is bellow:

```
var barchart = {
    xtype: 'cartesian',
    legend: {
        docked: 'bottom'
    },
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            columns: 1,
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{ 
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'Afficher DSO',
            listeners: {
                click: function(btn){
                    var dsoGrid = btn.nextSibling();

                    if( dsoGrid.hidden ){
                        helperCache.multiToolbox(dsoGrid, ["NOT_HIDE"]);
                        btn.setText("Masquer DSO");
                    } else {
                        helperCache.multiToolbox(dsoGrid, ["HIDE"]);
                        btn.setText("Afficher DSO");
                    }
                }
            }
        },{
            xtype: 'grid',
            itemId: 'grid_history_dso',
            // hidden: true,
            scrollable: 'x',
            margin: 5,
            flex: 1,
            store: dsoStore,
            columns: dsoColumns,
        }]
    }],
    .......
```

I like to my button take normal size, and my grid take fit all place of his container with x scroll

Answer (score 0):

For helping anyone in same case, i solved my problem with :

```
var barchart = {
    xtype: 'cartesian',
    legend: {
        docked: 'bottom'
    },
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        layout: {
            type: 'anchor',
        },
        items: [{ 
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'Afficher DSO',
            listeners: {
                click: function(btn){
                    var dsoGrid = btn.nextSibling();

                    if( dsoGrid.hidden ){
                        helperCache.multiToolbox(dsoGrid, ["NOT_HIDE"]);
                        btn.setText("Masquer DSO");
                    } else {
                        helperCache.multiToolbox(dsoGrid, ["HIDE"]);
                        btn.setText("Afficher DSO");
                    }
                }
            }
        },{
            xtype: 'grid',
            itemId: 'grid_history_dso',
            hidden: true,
            scrollable: 'x',
            margin: 5,
            anchor: '100%',
            store: dsoStore,
            columns: dsoColumns,
        }]
    }],
```

dockedItem was key